# Making a Chronometer c#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I'm trying to make a chronometer forms application that works both as a stopwatch and a countdown with ticking an option.
Problem is that I can't seem to be able to draw the miliseconds.
Right now, without the miliseconds the Tick method looks like this:

```
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timespan.TotalSeconds > 0)
        {
            timespan = timespan.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1));
            updateNumericUpDowns();
        }
        else
        {
            timerCountown.Stop();
        }
    }
```

The method for updating the UI:

```
    private void updateNumericUpDowns()
    {
        numericUpDownSeconds.Value = Convert.ToInt32(timespan.Seconds);
        numericUpDownMinutes.Value = Convert.ToInt32(timespan.Minutes);
        numericUpDownHours.Value = Convert.ToInt32(timespan.Hours);
    }
```

Help is appreciated, tnx everyone!

Comment: That's not going to be accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I'm following. Why not just use `timespan.Milliseconds`?

As it is, you're using hours, minutes, and seconds. If you want to show the milliseconds, then add that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I would trust "timer_Tick" for the millisecond resolution: If the system is under heavy load, will a tick be slower or faster than 1 second? (Will that affect the number of elapsed millis?) Try comparing the current time to a known starting time.

```
private DateTime startTime;

void StartTimer() {
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
    //start timer
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    timespan = currentTime - startTime; //positive
    bool hasCountdownTerminated = ... //maybe something like timespan < duration + timerResolution
    if (hasCountdownTerminated)
    {
        timerCountown.Stop();
    }
    else
    {
        updateNumericUpDowns();
    }
}    

void updateNumericUpDowns() {
    //use timespan.Milliseconds;
}
```